# swift - How to delay method call until variables value is stored regarding updating current location

Tags: swift, methods, delay, updates, currentlocation

I would like to call a method but it requires coordinates that have not been stored in variables yet.

So far I have:
1) acquired current location
2) Think I store them?

What I want to do:
1) Call method After these variables are stored so the program can run

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate  {

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var clLatitude : CLLocationDegrees!
var clLongitude: CLLocationDegrees!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


    }



func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate

    //Test printing coordinates to screen
    print("locations = \(location.self.clLatitude) \(location.self.clLongitude)")

    //place where I think I store the variables?
    self.clLatitude  = location.latitude
    self.clLongitude = location.longitude

}

func methodToBeCalled(){
     //to be called after variables are stored.
}
```

I believe I have covered everything regarding my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you just need to call the method at the end of `locationManager(manager: didUpdateLocations:)`

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate

    //Test printing coordinates to screen
    print("locations = \(location.self.clLatitude) \(location.self.clLongitude)")

    //place where I think I store the variables?
    self.clLatitude  = location.latitude
    self.clLongitude = location.longitude

    // call method
    methodToBeCalled()
}

func methodToBeCalled(){
     //to be called after variables are stored.
}
```

Comment: Im attempting this at the moment, my apologies for the late response, but trying to print to the screen to test and nothing within the "methodToBeCalled()" is printing to the screen. A silent fail? Grrrr

Comment: what I think this actually did do the trick, just that I had to go back and change the location under the debug dropdown to get it going! thank you!